# How to automatically fix the warning or errors when edit python using elpy of emacs?

Tags: emacs, elpy

Like the hint with wavy line under the lines of the code which tells E231 missing whitespace after ','

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/857. you could try `M-x elpy-autopep8-fix-code`